# iOS(Objective-C). Application crash when getting block from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

Have a question about blocks in objective-c.
For example I have a list of actions.
I'm initializing an array of blocks:

```
self.actions =  @[
                   ^() { [self showObject:self.object_1]; },
                   ^() { [self showObject:self.object_2]; },
                   ^() { [self showObject:self.object_3]; }
];
```

And calling them when some row is pressed:

```
- (void)pressedRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    if (index < actions.count) {
        void (^action)() = [actions objectAtIndex:index];
        if (action != nil) {
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

And all works fine without problem. But when I init my actions array by using `initWithObjects` method:

```
self.actions =  [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                   ^() { [self showObject:self.object_1]; },
                   ^() { [self showObject:self.object_2]; },
                   ^() { [self showObject:self.object_3]; },
                       nil
    ];
```

Than I get crash trying to get action by index by using `objectAtIndex` method of `NSArray` class.

I understand the difference between this inits. First one don't increase reference count like first do. But can someone explain why it crash?

**Edit:**

All that I've found. Maybe I'm nub and somewhere else is another useful information.
[image]

There is no crash info in terminal:
[image]

**Code for Onik IV:**

Small example:

```
@interface ViewController () {
    NSArray *actions;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *object1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *object2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *object3;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    actions =  [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                ^() { [self showObject:self.object1];},
                ^() { [self showObject:self.object2]; },
                ^() {[self showObject:self.object3]; },
                nil];



}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.object1 = @"object 1";
    self.object2 = @"object 2";
    self.object3 = @"object 3";

    void(^firsSimpleBlock)(void) = [actions lastObject];

    firsSimpleBlock();

    void(^simpleBlock)(void) = [actions firstObject];


    simpleBlock();
}

-(void)showObject:(NSString *)object
{
    NSLog(@"Show: %@",object);
}

@end
```

Comment: Please post the error message, stack trace, and specific line of the crash.

Comment: Are we talking about ARC?

Comment: @Cy-4AH yes. As I said I know the difference between that inits.

Comment: Press `Continue program execution` several times till exception got printed in output.

Comment: It could be that when you create a block it is created on the stack and when you add something to a array it's retain count will be increased so the object won't be removed leading to sail pointer in the NSArray. Blocks may need to be copied to the heap before put in the array(so they won't be removed when the frame is poped from the stack). So try to add the blocks to the array in a different way by addObject:[theBlock copy] or so.

Comment: I reread your post and are now even more sure.. When using literals in Objective-C the objects created there are allocated in a literal pool and never deallocated. While on the other hand when you create them dynamically they are separate objects allocated on the heap.

Comment: @PeterSegerblom and how to fix it?Newer heard about literal pool.

Comment: @VasylKhmil check my answer below. My block syntax might be wrong tho... but the concept is that you need to run copy on your blocks before putting them in the array.

Comment: @VasylKhmil, I think you are looking for the problem in the wrong place. Please give more information about object_1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    (^someBlock)(void) = ^void(void){
        self.object1; 
    };
    actions =  [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                [someBlock copy],
                [someOtherBlock copy],
                [anotherBlock copy],
                nil];



}
```

Blocks are allocated on the stack and are therefor removed when the frame is removed from the stack leading to sail pointers for all pointers pointing to that block. When you allocate a object with the literal "@" sign the object is allocated in a pool so all literals that are the "same" point to the same instance and are never deallocated.

```
NSString *a = @"A";
NSString *b = @"A";
```

points to the same instance of a string, while:

```
NSString *a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A"];
NSString *b = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A"];
```

are two different objects.

So it works when you are creating a literal array but when you add the blocks dynamically they will be removed when its time to use them therefor the BAD_ACCESS. Solution is to send "copy" message to the block that will copy it to the heap and the block will not be released.

Comment: explain please where is a problem, and why your code is solving that

Answer (score 0):

It´s the same, you must have another kind of problem (sintax?).

Try this:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *object1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *object2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *object3;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.object1 = @"object 1";
self.object2 = @"object 2";
self.object3 = @"object 3";


NSArray *actions =  @[^() { [self showObject:self.object1];},
                            ^() { [self showObject:self.object2]; },
                            ^() {[self showObject:self.object3]; }
                            ];

NSArray *secondActions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
^() { [self showObject:self.object1];},
^() { [self showObject:self.object2]; },
^() { [self showObject:self.object3];},
nil
];

void(^firsSimpleBlock)(void) = [actions lastObject];

firsSimpleBlock();

void(^simpleBlock)(void) = [secondActions firstObject];


simpleBlock();


}

-(void)showObject:(NSString *)object
{
NSLog(@"Show: %@",object);
}

@end
```

Comment: I think the problem is is cycling. All actions is using self, and self is using actions. But I don't understand why it cause a problem.

Comment: I have updated code too. You must more info. Are you using dispatch to send to background? What is object_1 and how is its getter?